# Rasa "OPTIONS /webhooks/rest/webhook HTTP/1.1" 404 341 0.000560

Tags: rasa-core

Rasa [2019-05-28 07:10:56] "OPTIONS /webhooks/rest/webhook HTTP/1.1" 404 341 0.000560

I'm trying to run rasa server but I'm getting this 404 error, anyone, no response from dialogue_management.py

Comment: Can you please add the used Python version, the used Rasa version, the command which you are using to run Rasa, and the log?

Comment: thanks for your response, was using python 3.6.7, I have resolved the issue, using this command `python3 -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/default/customer_service_chatbot --port 5005 --credentials credentials.yml --endpoints endpoints.yml --enable_api` and `python -m rasa_core_sdk.endpoint --actions actions`

Comment: awesome. can you then close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was using python 3.6.7, I have resolved the issue, using this command `python3 -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/default/customer_service_chatbot --port 5005 --credentials credentials.yml --endpoints endpoints.yml --enable_api` and `python -m rasa_core_sdk.endpoint --actions actions`